# Change button's text in JS without div.class

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom, button

**THE PROBLEM**

I've some hard time to change a button's text on my website.

There isn't a class on the `<div>` that I want to target and that's why I'm struggling with this edit.
To be honest, I've some basic knowledge of JS, so I can understand it, but I'm not good enough yet to find this solution myself.

There is the simplified code of the page :

```
<div class="notion-topbar">
  <div>
    <div class="notranslate">...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div role="button"> // I want to change the text in this <div>!
      <svg>...</svg> my_text
    </div>
```

If you prefer, you can watch the full page here and search "topbar": https://overwatch-guide.com
I want to translate in French the "Search" button on top right.

**POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS**

I maybe find a part of the solution, like using `document.querySelector('input[type=button]').innerHTML = "Rechercher";` but I know something is missing because I don't want to select all buttons on page.

I also find a sort of "hack" in CSS (a language that I'm more comfortable with), but I'm not a huge fan of this kind of solution because CSS isn't made to edit text. For my case, I've imagined this:

```
.notion-topbar > div:nth-child(1n+3) > .button {
  visibility: hidden
}

.notion-topbar > div:nth-child(1n+3) > .button:after {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  content: 'Rechercher';
  position: absolute;
}
```

**HELP**

I could really use your help because I'm hard struggling on this one.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Any CSS selector will work in JS. So the selectors from your "CSS hack" can be used inside the `document.querySelector` Or just right click the element in devtools and click -> copy -> copy selector

Comment: I wasn't quite sure about using CSS selector in my script.
So, do you mean I could try a script like this one?

document.querySelector('div.notion-topbar > div > div:nth-child(3)').innerHTML = "Rechercher";

Comment: If that is the correct CSS selector then yes that would work. Small tip, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` since it has some major security issues

Comment: Thanks for the `textContent` advice! I tried this script, but I can't figure why it's not working... document.querySelector(".notion-topbar > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)").textContent = "Rechercher";

Comment: It works for me, just copy pasted it into the console.

Comment: Yeah, for me too! I'm searching why I've this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null" when I try to apply the script on my worker.

Comment: Make sure the DOM is loaded before you execute your code. You could add a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event around the code to make sure it has loaded

Comment: I tried to add an event, but no change. I think I've find what's wrong: `querySelector` targets only 1st element, but 1st element of the `div` I want to target its an `svg` element (I've edited the syntax of my original post to show you). I tried to change my script with `querySelectorAll`, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I've added a answer for your problem, i hope it helps. There is indeed a SVG element and some text inside the button which makes it harder to just replace the textContent. You need to check if it is text and only replace that part of the html. My solution does that

Answer (score 0):

can you not assign the div an id if you don't want to use a class then you could just call it was follows
document.getElementById("YourIdName").innerHTML = "whatever";

Comment: It will certainly be easier, but I can't edit deeply the code on my webpage. I'm using a worker on Cloudflare which is fully scripted and "ready-to-use". I've already edited the script for some little modifications, but this one it's kindda hard to solve for me. Thanks for your answer anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this, maybe?

document.querySelector('div[role=button]')

Comment: Did this script will try to edit every div with button's role?
Because that's what I think it will do.

Comment: @Yani , No it'll only change first div with `role=button` because `document.querySelector` returns first element that matches the selector passed to it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I've completely forgotten what `document.querySelector`does, my bad! ^^ Anyway, even if @Reyno have found a solution for my issue, thx for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple nodes inside your button. You should check each item and if it is a text node replace the content.

PS: This function can be used for every type of element, not just buttons.

```js
const replaceTextInElement = (element, find, replace, searchInChildren = false) => {
  // Stop doing anything if the element is empty
  if (!element.hasChildNodes()) return;
  
  // Create regex to replace our provided word
  const regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
  
  // Loop over each child nodes of the element
  for(const childNode of element.childNodes) {
    // Replace the text if it is a text node
    if(childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      // Replace the text with new text
      childNode.textContent = childNode.textContent.replace(regex, replace);
    } else if(searchInChildren) {
      // Also replace text in children if we specified it to do so
      replaceTextInElement(childNode, find, replace, searchInChildren);
    }
  }
}

// Don't do anything until the DOM is loaded
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search-button");
  // Use the line below. I used the one above because i was to lazy to recreate all the html.
  // const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".notion-topbar > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)");
  replaceTextInElement(searchBtn, "Search", "Rechercher");

  // You can also go through each child if you need to by adding true as parameter
  const anotherBtn = document.querySelector(".another-button");
  replaceTextInElement(anotherBtn, "Search", "Zoeken", true);
});
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
  <div>Search level 2 (your SVG)</div>
  Search level 1
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="another-button">
  <div>Search level 2 (your SVG)</div>
  Search level 1
</div>
```

Without comments:

```js
const replaceTextInElement = (element, find, replace, searchInChildren = false) => {
  if (!element.hasChildNodes()) return;
  
  const regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
  
  for(const childNode of element.childNodes) {
    if(childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      childNode.textContent = childNode.textContent.replace(regex, replace);
    } else if(searchInChildren) {
      replaceTextInElement(childNode, find, replace, searchInChildren);
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search-button");
  replaceTextInElement(searchBtn, "Search", "Rechercher");

  const anotherBtn = document.querySelector(".another-button");
  replaceTextInElement(anotherBtn, "Search", "Zoeken", true);
});
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
  <div>Search level 2 (your SVG)</div>
  Search level 1
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="another-button">
  <div>Search level 2 (your SVG)</div>
  Search level 1
</div>
```

Since the DOM isn't available even after the `DOMContentLoaded` event. The only option you have is a timer, though this is more of a hacky way to solve the problem then a fix. This last example tries to update the text every second. It will only stop updating if it succeeds or if it has hit the max amount of tries (limit). You can of course increase the waiting time (1000 milliseconds) or the amount of tries (10)

```js
const replaceTextInElement = (element, find, replace, searchInChildren = false) => {
  if (!element.hasChildNodes()) return;
  
  const regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
  
  for(const childNode of element.childNodes) {
    if(childNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      childNode.textContent = childNode.textContent.replace(regex, replace);
    } else if(searchInChildren) {
      replaceTextInElement(childNode, find, replace, searchInChildren);
    }
  }
}

const replaceSearchText = (attempts, limit) => {
  if(attempts > limit) return;
  
  const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".search-button");
  // Use the line below. I used the one above because i was to lazy to recreate all the html.
  // const searchBtn = document.querySelector(".notion-topbar > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)");
  
  searchBtn
    ? replaceTextInElement(searchBtn, "Search", "Rechercher")
    : setTimeout(() => replaceSearchText(attempts + 1, limit), 1000);
};

replaceSearchText(0, 10);
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
  <div>Search level 2 (your SVG)</div>
  Search level 1
</div>
```

Comment: To be honest, this code is way too complicated for me to understand completely atm. I guess I still have much to learn about JS! ^^ Anyway, I tried it on my site... but unfortunately, same result as before. I'm slowly trying to check what's wrong in your code example, I'm not giving up! It's still live if you want to check it by yourself. Currently, there is an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of null`.

Comment: @Yani I did dome more research and found out that the DOM gets added after the page has loaded meaning the event 'DOMContentLoaded' has already fired. The only other option is a timer like solution. See last snippet for example

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks for your help, you did an amazing job! I'm really grateful for your efforts. See you! :)